# Retrofit 2.7.1 is not working in android show failed to connect java.net.ConnectException

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit for my android app. It work perfectly, but when I 
updated Retrofit to 2.7.1 it stop working.

I try to connect the endpoint "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
but it shows

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/2606:4700:3035::681b:99d1:443
```

Comment: What is your **minSdk** version?

Comment: minSdkVersion 15

Comment: Retrofit 2.7 uses OkHttp 3.*, which requires  Java 8+ or Android 5+. If you want to support pre lollipop devices use Reftrofit 2.3.  Ref: [https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/]